# Bookmarks and History Buttons not showing up in my Browser using JavaFX

Tags: java

I am making a web browser in JavaFX and I thought everything was good and dandy. I ran the application and now the History and Bookmarks buttons will not appear. I looked through the code and saw no errors. How do I fix this?

```
package javafxapplication3;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;

public class CreateAsIGo2 extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        BorderPane ap = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane ap2 = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane ap3 = new BorderPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(ap, 700, 700);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(ap2, 700, 700);
        Scene scene3 = new Scene(ap3, 700, 700);

        VBox sp = new VBox();
        VBox sp2 = new VBox();
        VBox sp3 = new VBox();

        Button HistoryButton = new Button("History");
        Button BookmarksButton = new Button("Bookmarks");        
        Button RefreshButton = new Button("Refresh");
        Button BackButton = new Button("Back");
        Button BackToBrowser = new Button("Back to surfing the web");
        Button ForwardButton = new Button("Forward");

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setPromptText("URL");

        WebView browser = new WebView();

        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();



        HistoryButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));
        BookmarksButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene3));
        RefreshButton.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.reload());        
        BackButton.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.executeScript("history.back()"));        
        BackToBrowser.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene));        
        ForwardButton.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.executeScript("history.forward()"));

        tf.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            KeyCode key = ke.getCode();
            if(key == KeyCode.ENTER){
                webEngine.load("http://" + tf.getText());
            }
        });

        sp.getChildren().addAll(HistoryButton, BookmarksButton, RefreshButton, BackButton, ForwardButton);
        sp2.getChildren().addAll(BookmarksButton, BackToBrowser);
        sp3.getChildren().addAll(HistoryButton, BackToBrowser);

        ap.setRight(sp);
        ap2.setRight(sp2);
        ap3.setRight(sp3);
        ap.setTop(tf);
        ap.setCenter(browser);

        browser.setPrefSize(700, 700);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JTG Browser Alpha");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [node documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent.

You are adding your `HistoryButton` (and other buttons) to different scenes and, when you do so, they are automatically removed from the previous scenes.  You need to create new button instances if you want them visible in every scene.

Small aside: it is best to follow Java naming conventions, e.g. `historyButton` instead of `HistoryButton`.